# Get sys_category items to show up in menu via dataProcessing / DatabaseQueryProcessor

Tags: typo3, typoscript, data-processing, typo3-9.x

The menu works. But cats is always empty. `data.categories` shows the count of how many categories are assigned to the given page. But cats array only shows: `cats => array(empty)`. What's wrong with my TYPOSCRIPT?

```
        40 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        40 {
            expandAll = 1
            levels = 7
            as = menuMain
            dataProcessing {
                100 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
                100 {
                    if.isTrue.field = categories
                    table = sys_category
                    select {
                        pidInList = root,-1
                        selectFields = sys_category.*
                        join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
                        where.data = field:_ORIG_uid // field:uid
                        where.intval = 1
                        where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=|
                        orderBy = sys_category_record_mm.sorting_foreign
                        languageField = 0 # disable translation handling of sys_category
                    }
                    as = cats
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "select" parameter for the DatabaseQueryProcessor.
So you should remove it and move all the sub-parameters one level up.

```
    40 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
    40 {
        expandAll = 1
        levels = 7
        as = menuMain
        dataProcessing {
            100 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            100 {
                if.isTrue.field = categories
                table = sys_category
                pidInList = root,-1
                selectFields = sys_category.*
                join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
                where.data = field:_ORIG_uid // field:uid
                where.intval = 1
                where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=|
                orderBy = sys_category_record_mm.sorting_foreign
                languageField = 0 # disable translation handling of sys_category
                as = cats
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this version limited? I'm trying to get it to work in V11 but only get an empty array ...

Comment: Look at the code section in my recent edit. This should work with other TYPO3 versions too. You might have to check if the fields used in that query still exist, but the construct itself should be working.

Comment: I see that the DatabaseQueryProcessor is within the MenuProcessor dataProcessing, is that part of the reason it works? I'm not used to do it like that but sequential with augmenting numbering

Comment: The point is, that you can nest data processors and the result of each processor will be attached to the items of the parent processor.

In this case it means that you create menuMain items with the menu processor which will be enhanced with categories attached to each item using a nested DatabaseQueryProcessor.

Comment: makes good sense ... so the final question is: how do I nest it in the data-array ? I cannot find where that array gets proccesed, I need the selected sys_categories for a content element

Comment: There should be an array in the key menuMain, containing  arrays of menu items, which again should contain a key cats, containing the ctageories.

But if you are talking about content elements, the question is, if you are on the right track with a menu processor. So maybe you should make it a new question since it might be something different than the original question here.

Comment: I did a week ago as a viewhelper ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231270/how-to-get-the-selected-categories-for-an-ce-in-the-selected-language ... was getting no answer so I kept on looking for options ... but now I worked it out

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `recursive = 99` to look for all pages.
I have an example with categories that works, see: https://github.com/spoonerWeb/just_news/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/RenderingDefinitions/news_list.ts

Comment: I completely copied the dataProcessing part of your example, but still have an empty array.

Comment: You have categories in your pages?

Comment: yes :) the counting as an integer of the categories applied works.

Comment: Be careful with large websites! With `recursive = 99` the entire pagetree is queried page by page for its subpages to build the list of IDs. On a site with 10T pages this caused (uncached) almost 25,000 SQL queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
50 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
50 {
  if.isTrue.field = categories
  table = sys_category
  pidInList = root,-1
  selectFields = sys_category.*
  recursive = 99
  as = categories
}
```

just this worked out for me.

Comment: Be careful with large websites! With `recursive = 99` the entire pagetree is queried page by page for its subpages to build the list of IDs. On a site with 10T pages this caused (uncached) almost 25,000 SQL queries.